# How does the weighting system procedure in machine learning work?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, naivebayes

In Weka, we have a option to assign weights to some instances especially when the data set is imbalance in terms of the classes. But what I cannot understand is how does this weighting system work?

For example: When we use Naive Bayes  or decision tree as classification algorithms on a data set with some instances which have weight of 5, does it mean that those instances are considered 5 times by the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samples weighting is **classifier specific**. There is no one, universal answer. Simply many classifiers (as well as regressors) have their own internal methods of using samples weights. For many of them, it is equivalent of thinking about it in terms of samples replication, however remember that weights **can be arbitrary, positive real numbers**, thus you can weight by `pi` even though you cannot replicate a sample `pi` times. In case of Naive Bayes - samples weights are used inside the probability estimators to proportionaly weight each sample, thus it is equivalent to replication (if you put **integer** weight). For decision trees it is way more complicated, and for arbitrary method - the answer is model/implementation specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot just to make sure I am in the same page, by replication you mean for example if I have an instance with weight of 3 it means I have 3 of that instance in my data set am I right?

Comment: Yes, for many algorithms (and integer weights) it would work like this. However - as stated in the answer - this is not always the case (it is purely classifier implementation dependent)

Comment: I have one more question : I have test set and train set so when I apply weighing on train set my measures does not improve that much but when I apply it on test set the improvement is noteworthy now I am wondering is it reasonable to apply weighting on test set?

Comment: No, you never weight the test set. How would you do it?  You do not know labels od test set

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea how to choose the weight? I mean is there any procedure or defined way instead of picking it randomly?

Comment: it depends what you are trying to optimize (what is the cost function/metric), but in general there are only rules of the thumb